# Android/Kotlin - Fragment not attached to Activity after loosing focus on textfield by pressing navigation menu button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, textview, lost-focus

i've a problem in my Android app.

I have a fragment that is generated as a list of editable textview. Every textview has a *setOnFocusChangeListener* that calls an API on server.
*FocusChangedListener* works correctly on last textview, and after that my textview remain focused as you can see in the figure below.

[image]

### Problem

Now i have to change menu (fragment) by clicking on the right menu button.
When button is clicked and the new menu is about to be loaded, my textview loses focus and calls the API, but **i don't want my app do that**. If I click menu button is because i've to change it and i expect that my old fragment disappear or basically don't execute the FocusChangedListener.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little trick to **solve the problem**.
I just added this code inside OnCreate of my DrawerMenu and then i set a Global Variable "*drawerOpened*" to check every time if my Menu is open or not.

```
        // Initialize the action bar drawer toggle instance
    val drawerToggle:ActionBarDrawerToggle = object : ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,
        drawer_layout,
        toolbar,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    ){
        override fun onDrawerClosed(view:View){
            super.onDrawerClosed(view)
            GlobalVar.drawerOpened = false
        }

        override fun onDrawerOpened(drawerView: View){
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView)
            GlobalVar.drawerOpened = true
            currentFocus?.clearFocus()  //clear focus - any view having focus
        }
    }
```

Then in my HomeFragment i did this:

```
// if GlobalVar.drawerOpened is false then setOnFocus

if (field.validatefield || field.nextpage != 0)
{
  textView.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    if (!hasFocus && !GlobalVar.drawerOpened)
    {
        if ((field.mandatory && !textView.text.toString().isNullOrEmpty()) || (!field.mandatory)) {
            if (field.validatefield) {
                validateField(field.fieldcode, textView.text.toString(), field.nextpage)
            } else {
                _goToNextPageNo = field.nextpage
                goToNextPageIfExist()
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This is not a complete solution, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that after a click, the application switches to touch mode and your EditText loses focus.
It happens at the system level.

A focus can have only one view at a time.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html

Comment: It's ok that a focus can have only one view, but i don't understand why this happens when i change Fragment. And i need to know how to fix that.

Comment: Your edit text loses focus because your app 1) proceeds to the touch mode and then 2) one the side menu item gets focus. I think so.

Comment: see my answer below